# SwiftUI: how to make a view fit into a certain size

Tags: swift, swiftui, frontend, spacing

So basically I have this view in my app.
[image]

I want the box named LaMarcus Aldridge be the same size as the rest Basically I want to reduce the size of the box by reducing the amount of space between the picture and lines of text so that all boxes are the same size. I originally thought about going about it mathematically by calculating the space needed, but I am pretty sure that there is better way to do this that I am just no thinking of. Thank you I really appreciate it.

Here is the code that declared those boxes.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) { //first
            Image(uiImage: question.players[0].picture)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 140)
//                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            
            Text(question.players[0].name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(2)
            
            Text(question.players[0].team)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            selectedAnswer = question.players[0]
        })
        
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(color(option: question.players[0]), lineWidth: 5)
        )
        .cornerRadius(15)
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) { //second
            Image(uiImage: question.players[1].picture)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 140)
            Text(question.players[1].name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(2)
            
            Text(question.players[1].team)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            selectedAnswer = question.players[1]
        })
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(color(option: question.players[1]), lineWidth: 5)
        )
        .cornerRadius(15)
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) { //third
            Image(uiImage: question.players[2].picture)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 140)
            Text(question.players[2].name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(2)
            
            Text(question.players[2].team)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            selectedAnswer = question.players[2]
        })
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(color(option: question.players[2]), lineWidth: 5)
        )
        .cornerRadius(15)
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) { //fourth
            Image(uiImage: question.players[3].picture)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 140)
            Text(question.players[3].name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(2)
            
            Text(question.players[3].team)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            selectedAnswer = question.players[3]
        })
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(color(option: question.players[3]), lineWidth: 5)
        )
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
```

Comment: Maybe check out LazyVStack if you’re on iOS 14+

Comment: Your question is wrong! You should limit and fix Image and Text to certain size, then all views with same function would be fit

Comment: try the grid system, 
`var gridLayout = [GridItem(.fixed(180)),GridItem(.fixed(180))] `
wrapping the VStacks in something like: 
`LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 10) {..VStacks..}` and 
replace, `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` of each VStack with 
`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 280)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use conditional in VStack.
I've created a custom card view that you can use in your content view, with LazyVGrid + ForEach or simply with HStack and VStack.

```
struct CardView: View{
var playerName: String
var playerTeam: String
var playerPortrait: UIImage
var body: some 
View{
 
//Control amount of spacing depend on amount of character in player's name
VStack(spacing: playerName.count  > 13 ? -12 : 0) { //first
    Image(uiImage: playerPortrait)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height:160)
                .padding(10)
            
            Text(playerName)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding(5)
            
            Text(playerTeam)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(5)
}.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke()).padding(5)
}
}
```